# Why isn't this looping over my whole file of zip codes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

When I run my code and add print statements within my for-loop, the zip code, city, and region print out correctly for the first zip code but it never progresses to my next zip code. When I print out my DataFrame, all values are set to NaN.

I've tried running a general for-loop to print each zip code separately in PyCharm and it only prints the first zip code but when I run the same code in Jupyter Notebook, every zip code is printed

```
for z in zipcodes:

    # gets the website to find the closest big city
    res = requests.get('https://www.travelmath.com/cities-near/' + z)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#EchoTopic > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(8) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2)')
    place = elems[0].text.strip()
    city, state = place.split(',')

    # uses the city found above to find the text in the webpage and the region it corresponds to
    newres = requests.get('https://www.almanac.com/weather/longrange')
    newsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(newres.text, 'html.parser')
    newelems = newsoup.find('td', text=city).parent.parent
    alltext = newelems.text
    region = find_region(alltext) # helper regex function I wrote

    # appends the zip code, city, and region to the DataFrame
    regions.append([z, city, region])
```

prints out only the first zip code, city, and region and returns a DataFrame of NaNs instead of printing out almost 4,000 zip codes and their related information and doesn't write any of it to the DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the append dataframe method you need to do an assignment.

Try to add:

```
regions = regions.append([z,city,region])
```

Comment: So that helped to update the DataFrame but I still can't get it to loop to the next zip code. I've checked the length of the list and added print statements to see if it starts the loop again and it never does.

Answer (score 0):

The code was attempting to loop over the columns of my DataFrame which happened to be the first zip code because my csv didn't have a column title in it. Along with Dan Wisner's answer, I changed:

```
for i in zipcodes.index:
    z = zipcodes.iloc[i]['zip codes']
    res = requests.get('https://www.travelmath.com/cities-near/' + str(z))
    ...
```